Can I set up go linter to disallow assignment to bound variable in function closures?
Go allows people to do assignment on bound variable in function closures (example: A Tour of Go).
func adder() func(int) int {
    sum := 0
    return func(x int) int {
        sum += x
        return sum
    }
}

This has led to a few race condition bugs in our codebase. I wonder if there's a way to set up the linter to disallow this assignment operation in function closures (the = in sum += x). (E.g. in python you need the nonlocal keyword to do the same thing)
I have searched the internet but couldn't find people with the same problem. Not sure if this problem is unique to our codebase and company.

How would you write that function with that linter turned on?

This is nothing unique to your codebase. Concurrency issues arise from shared variables, and specific or limited to closures. Same race condition applies if you didn't use a closure but passed &sum to the anonymous function. You have to be mindful of shared variables in any concurrent setting.
